# Set goproxy in cloud build on deploying to appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-build

We are deploying our Go app to Google app engine with the command: gcloud app deploy

This creates a cloud build, which normally works fine. However, sometimes there are some dependencies which are flaky (sometimes unavailable or down) or gone (revision no longer existing).

These issues break our complete deploy and build and we can only get rid of the dependency or wait until it is fixed on that side.

Solution for this is using a proxy for the go dependencies (like https://proxy.golang.org/), but I don't have any way of setting this setting for our app engine deployments.

Does anyone know how I can use a proxy for google app engine deploys to make our builds more stable?

Comment: Are you deploying on App Engine standard? If so did you considered Cloud Run?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere yes we are deploying on app engine standard and have so done for years. So we do not want to migrate to cloud run at this time (also not yet considering it just for this). Moving to cloud run can't be the only solution for this, right?

Comment: Which version of Go are you using?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere we are using go 1.11, as newer versions don't really work well on app engine yet (issues with time outs on task queues as that dependency is still in beta and not working well).

Comment: Arf.... `GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org/,direct` is set by default in version 1.13+. Task queue are obsolete. I recommend you to migrate to Cloud Task ASAP. Anyway, I tried lot of things, you can't customize today the AppEngine packaging. You can do it with Cloud Run because you build your own container. You can also deploy this same container on App Engine Flex custom runtime (but you don't scale to 0).

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere ah ok. We want to move to newer versions of go yes. But like I said the tasks are not working there for us. We are already using Cloud Task, so I am not sure what you mean with migration in this case. We get stuck in each cloud task getting an error. But I guess this migration issue is a different issue. I will try again and see if we can fix that.

Comment: Yes, try to ask a question on your task issues, it's strange I never had this issues!